# GCM register didnot work on my emulator

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I had use GCM service on my app , I did my code after more resarches also from stack overflow members , and when I try to test the code on my emulator I didn't find any regiser info that tell me that my emulator is registered .Also I created my account on Google API to recienve any reports but I didn't find any thing. So I need your help on:

1- please check my code and till my when the error I will feedback you with complete example :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.elarabygroup"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.elarabygroup.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.elarabygroup.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ElarabyGroup"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_elaraby_group" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.elarabygroup" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <!--
            android:name=".GCMIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
package com.example.elarabygroup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;


public class ElarabyGroup extends Activity {
    private String TAG;
    private String SENDER_ID = "222874571774";
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_elaraby_group);

        try {

            Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(
                    "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");

            /* Registering for GCM /An Android application needs to register with GCM servers before it can receive messages*/
            registrationIntent.putExtra("app",
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
            registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", SENDER_ID);
            startService(registrationIntent);

            Log.i(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] checkDevice");
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
            Log.i(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] checkManifest");
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this)) {
                Log.i(TAG,
                        "[checkNotifRegistration] reg id : "
                                + GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
            }
            final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
            if (regId.equals("")) {
                // SENDER_ID is my project id into google account url
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
                Log.i(TAG,
                        "[checkNotifRegistration] reg id : "
                                + GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] already registered as : "
                        + regId);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "[checkNotifRegistration] Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this); GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
         * 
         * 
         * final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this); if
         * (regId.equals("")) { GCMRegistrar.register(this, "1111111111"); }
         * else { Log.v(TAG, "Already registered"); }
         */
        try {

            ConnectivityManager con = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if (con.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
                    && con.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                builder.setMessage("No Internet connection");
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else

            {

                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl("http://m.elarabygroup.com");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage().toString());

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            String url = "http://m.elarabygroup.com/";

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

        }

    }
    /*
    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            GCMIntenetService.runIntentInService(context, intent);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
        }
    }
    */

}
/*
 * @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 * getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_elaraby_group, menu); return true;
 * } }
 */
```

```
package com.example.elarabygroup;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.util.Log;

public class GCMIntenetService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    private static  String GCM_SENDER_ID = "1111111111111";

    public GCMIntenetService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            String regId = "";
            Log.i(TAG, "unregistering device (regId = " + regId + ")");
            GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
        } else {
            // This callback results from the call to unregister made on
            // ServerUtilities when the registration to the server failed.
            Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring unregister callback");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // push error processing
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        Log.i(TAG, "EXTRAS" + arg1.getExtras());
        // String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
        generateNotification(arg0,
                arg1.getStringExtra("Please download our new updates"));
        // notifies user about message

    }

    private void generateNotification(Context arg0, String stringExtra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void registerInGCMService(Context context) {

        GCM_SENDER_ID = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);


        if (!checkIsGCMServiceAvailable(context)) {
            return;
        }
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            try {
                GCMRegistrar.register(context, GCM_SENDER_ID);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        } else {
            // Already registered
        }

    }

    public static boolean checkIsGCMServiceAvailable(Context context) {
        try {
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I had attached my log cat message

2- what about  status in my Google API account

Service                                         Status
Google Cloud Messaging for Android      No known issues

[image: Log cat]

[image: emulator message]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

first set your emulator target to Google API and add an google account to your emulator.

Comment: I had attached the log cat image also how can I add Google account on emulator

Comment: make sure you are using emulator targetted on Google API

Comment: you can add account on emulator as setting->account&sync in that you have an option Add account

Comment: the project message stopped appeared

Comment: I followed this URL well , also I am beginner on JAVA so if you try to help me ,this will be happy .

Comment: hey there is error in your manifest you have to add your intent receiver like this:- <service
            android:name="com.think.GCMTest.GCMIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" /> you hae forgot to add   android:enabled="true"

Comment: com.think.GCMTest will be my package name

Comment: no no thats just an example in your manifest you have commentted  android:enabled="true" uncomment it

Comment: got my point or not ??? your getting error becasue you have missed android:enabled="true" line for more info:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Answer (score 7):

**add google account to your emulator:**

setting->account&sync-> Add account **(from @curious_mind comment)**

> If the emulator is running Android 4.0.4 or later, this step is optional as GCM does not require an account from this version on.

for me it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

just you can use [this emulator](http://girishbhutiya.blogspot.in/2012/09/testing-push-notification-android-market-in-emulator.html) and test your application in this emulator i think it will work fine.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?2sr9d3hz44pjodc     
Use upper url for download emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an emulator for GCM functionality but you need to track some points as your emulator version should be 2.2 or above and contains Google API(must). Once you created this emulator AVD then follow the followig steps in emulator:
1.) goto Settings --> Accounts & Sync,
2.) then add a Google account and sync is on.
3.) Define internet permission in manifest file

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

4.) Define GCM related permissions in manifest

Once this is done, you should be ready to register for GCM and receive messages from it.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. can you read again this post ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Go to your android SDK folder and open SDK Manager and install Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library under Extras section. (If you don’t see Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library update your SDK manager to latest version)

After installing the library it will create gcm.jar file in your Andoird_SDK_Folder\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\dist. Later you need to add this .jar file to your android project.

First set your emulator target to Google API.

After launching emulator press Menu button goto Settings. Select Accounts & Sync. And then press Add Account button and add a Google account

Finally Test your Application on Simulator.