# gcm service_not_available on any device emulator

Tags: android

i have read most post about this argument but i not resolved my problem.

I have installed my app on my Samsung S2 and on emulator whit same api (vers. android 4.1.2 on my S2 and api level 16 on emulator)

The steps:

I run my emulatore with api level 16 Google API (Google inc.)
I add account google on emulator
Internet connection is available on emulator
But i receive always service_not_available when the app run on emulator and all work fine if i run app on my Samsung S2.

Help me pls!

Comment: You can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188982/how-to-fix-google-cloud-messaging-registration-error-service-not-available, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766119/google-cloud-messaging-service-not-available and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404012/gcm-register-didnot-work-on-my-emulator

Comment: i have read all 3 links. 
Still not work my app.
I tried also to import in build path gcm.jar

Comment: i have also added google account in the emulator.
correct permission in manifest
set the correct time and date
STILL NOT WORK