# Is it possible to receive GCM notification in Android emulator?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have tried many ways to receive GCM notification in Android emulator But it fails.But for other emulators like Geny Motion it works why??

Comment: Are you using GoogleApi emulator?

Comment: You must use Google Services like GCM, as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521600/android-emulator-not-receiving-push-notifications.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404012/gcm-register-didnot-work-on-my-emulator

Comment: I am using google api emulator version 21

Comment: Looks like you can:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521600/android-emulator-not-receiving-push-notifications